# Use extracted Listview.builder with two lists in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm a beginner in Flutter.

I designed this page:

[image]

Instead of repeating the entire Listview.builder. I would like to use two instances of custom Listview.builder with two lists, one list for fruits, and the other for vegetables.

As appeared in the above screen, I tried to display vegetables in the vegetables section through the following:

Listview.builder Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grocery_store/models/products_list.dart';

import '../utilities/add_product.dart';
import '../utilities/constants.dart';

class ProductsListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? productImage;
  final String? productName;
  final String? productCategory;
  final String? productPrice;

  const ProductsListView({
    Key? key,
    this.productImage,
    this.productName,
    this.productCategory,
    this.productPrice,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: fruitsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            width: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 10, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    fruitsList[index].fruitImage!,
                    height: 80.0,
                    width: 90.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            fruitsList[index].fruitName!,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            fruitsList[index].fruitCategory!,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              height: 1.5,
                              color: kDarkGrey,
                              fontSize: 12.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        fruitsList[index].fruitPrice!,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const AddProduct(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Fruits and vegetables lists:

```
import '../utilities/constants.dart';

class Fruits {
  final String? fruitImage;
  final String? fruitName;
  final String? fruitCategory;
  final String? fruitPrice;

  Fruits(
      {this.fruitImage, this.fruitName, this.fruitCategory, this.fruitPrice});
}

final Fruits bananas = Fruits(
  fruitImage: '${kFruitsImagesAsset}bananas.png',
  fruitName: 'Bananas',
  fruitCategory: 'Organic',
  fruitPrice: '\$4.99',
);

final Fruits apples = Fruits(
  fruitImage: '${kFruitsImagesAsset}apples.png',
  fruitName: 'Apples',
  fruitCategory: 'Organic',
  fruitPrice: '\$5.00',
);

final Fruits chikku = Fruits(
  fruitImage: '${kFruitsImagesAsset}chikku.png',
  fruitName: 'Chikku',
  fruitCategory: 'Organic',
  fruitPrice: '\$9.00',
);

final Fruits peaches = Fruits(
  fruitImage: '${kFruitsImagesAsset}peaches.png',
  fruitName: 'Peaches',
  fruitCategory: 'Organic',
  fruitPrice: '\$12.00',
);

List<Fruits> fruitsList = [bananas, apples, chikku, peaches];

class Vegetables {
  final String? vegetableImage;
  final String? vegetableName;
  final String? vegetableCategory;
  final String? vegetablePrice;

  Vegetables(
      {this.vegetableImage,
      this.vegetableName,
      this.vegetableCategory,
      this.vegetablePrice});
}

final Vegetables okra = Vegetables(
  vegetableImage: '${kVegetablesImagesAsset}okra.png',
  vegetableName: 'Okra',
  vegetableCategory: 'Organic',
  vegetablePrice: '\$6.99',
);

final Vegetables peas = Vegetables(
  vegetableImage: '${kVegetablesImagesAsset}peas.png',
  vegetableName: 'Peas',
  vegetableCategory: 'Organic',
  vegetablePrice: '\$10.50',
);

final Vegetables potatoes = Vegetables(
  vegetableImage: '${kVegetablesImagesAsset}potatoes.png',
  vegetableName: 'Potatoes',
  vegetableCategory: 'Organic',
  vegetablePrice: '\$5.99',
);

final Vegetables taro = Vegetables(
  vegetableImage: '${kVegetablesImagesAsset}taro.png',
  vegetableName: 'Taro',
  vegetableCategory: 'Organic',
  vegetablePrice: '\$5.50',
);

List<Vegetables> vegetablesList = [okra, peas, potatoes, taro];
```

Homepage where I want to display the two lists:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:grocery_store/models/product_cards_column.dart';
import 'package:grocery_store/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:grocery_store/utilities/grocery_text_field.dart';

import '../models/products_cards.dart';
import '../models/products_list.dart';

class GroceryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroceryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var discountPortrait =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 1, 0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Grocery',
                        style: kTitleTextStyle,
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/apple.jpg',
                          width: 46.0,
                          height: 46.0,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(children: [
                  GroceryTextField.groceryTextField(
                    groceryText: 'Search...',
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                  Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      color: kLightGrey,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'images/funnel.svg',
                        semanticsLabel: 'Funnel',
                        color: kDarkGrey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    color: const Color(0xFFE9F9F2),
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: -150,
                        right: discountPortrait ? -30 : 30,
                        height: 290,
                        width: 430,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          '${kProductsImagesAsset}lettuce.png',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: discountPortrait ? 35 : 15,
                        left: discountPortrait ? 25 : 100,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Get Up To',
                              style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: discountPortrait ? 20 : 60,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '%10 off',
                              style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: 40.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: const [
                    ProductCardsRow(
                      groceryType: 'Fruits',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 215,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ProductsListView(
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: const [
                    ProductCardsRow(
                      groceryType: 'Vegetables',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 215,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ProductsListView(
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an other variable in constructor and call it `list` and pass your `Vegetables` and `Fruits` to it like this:

```
class ProductsListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List list;

  const ProductsListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.list,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        
        return ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            width: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 10, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    list is List<Fruits> ? (list[index] as Fruits).fruitImage! : (list[index] as Vegetables).vegetableImage!,
                    height: 80.0,
                    width: 90.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            list is List<Fruits> ? (list[index] as Fruits).fruitName! : (list[index] as Vegetables).vegetableName!,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            list is List<Fruits> ? (list[index] as Fruits).fruitCategory! : (list[index] as Vegetables).vegetableCategory!
                            
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              height: 1.5,
                              color: kDarkGrey,
                              fontSize: 12.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        list is List<Fruits> ? (list[index] as Fruits).fruitPrice! : (list[index] as Vegetables).vegetablePrice!,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const AddProduct(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 215,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: ProductsListView(
       list: vegetablesList,
    ),
),
SizedBox(
    height: 215,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: ProductsListView(
       list: fruitsList,
    ),
),
```

Comment: How to add them in ProductsListView() in the last two columns in GroceryPage() class?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is pretty straightfroward, just click on the `listview.builder` method in your project and then click on **FLutter Outline** on the right hand side of the Android Studio IDE window, like this :

[image: FLutter Outline]

Once you have done that the ListView.Builder will be visible in this tree of widgets. What you need to do is to **right click on the widget you want to extract and then click on extract method**.
you'll get a dialog asking for the name of the newly created widget :

[image: Dialog Box for widget name]

and a new widget will be created at the bottom of your file.
Just change the parameters for both the listview.builders and it'll look something like this :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return CommonList(typeList: fruitslist); // use this to change the list
 }
```

And in the newly created widget you'd need to do the same:

```
class CommonList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List typeList; //add a list parameter 
  const CommonList({
    Key? key, required this.typeList, //request that list parameter
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: typeList.length, // change the list type
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            width: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 10, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    typeList[index].fruitImage!, //update list to use it everywhere
                    height: 80.0,
                    width: 90.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            typeList[index].fruitName!, //like here
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            typeList[index].fruitCategory!, //here
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              height: 1.5,
                              color: kDarkGrey,
                              fontSize: 12.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        typeList[index].fruitPrice!, //and here again
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const AddProduct(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I already did this, the problem than I don't know how to use the extracted Listview.builder with the fruits and vegetables lists

Comment: Check it now I've added the whole code which you'd require

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: no problems. :)